# Unity Ads or Google Ads wich one is better?

Tags: unity, advertisements

I don't know if i can ask this here, but i have a doubt about wich ad advertiser is better, a friend said unity and other said google... I want to know in general wich one is better? If there's one wich is better than both let me know. If i can't ask this here let me know and i delete this question :D thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using Google ads as the ad revenue is higher and you will start to tell thus as you get more impressions. It is also rather easy to set up and has a nice UI. You also have better flexibility in how ads are placed and there is more demand for Google advertising. You should use Adobe to set it up.